# use profile property of matlab in function

Tags: matlab, function

let us consider following code

```
function  [y,m]=fibonacci(n);
% return nth fibonnaci number
profile on
y=zeros(1,n);
y(1)=0;
y(2)=1;
 for k=3:n
     y(k)=y(k-1)+y(k-2);
 end
 m=y(n);
 profile viewer
p = profile('info');
profsave(p,'profile_results')
end
```

of course  i can use tic and toc  function in matlab to calculate how  much time will taken by this function, but i want for self learning ,  customize with profile tools in matlab, for instance let us consider following little code

```
profile on
plot(magic(35))
profile viewer
p = profile('info');
profsave(p,'profile_results')
```

result is given
[image]

i want to  use same property in function, but is says that now built in function is used here, so can i use profile properties in function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually works but when the function is terminated, the function workspace is deleted. You can check this by add a BreakPoint as follows:

[image]

I think there is no way that you can see the information just using a **single function** as you requested.
But you always can have a **main file** and profile the function from there, and the profiler gives you all of the information:

```
% --------- main.m --------
profile on
fibonacci(100);
profile viewer
p = profile('info');
profsave(p,'profile_results')
% --------------------------
```

Comment: yes thanks in advance i have tried same, thanks for  your help